# Encoding site to https wrecked menu

Tags: javascript, https, responsive

https://www.klc.co.nz

I have used the encoding option with my webhost to make my site secure (http to https) but this has removed the responsive element of the menu and also a javascript-driven text animation in the header.

Any ideas on how I can fix this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened because your js files not loaded
Press F12 and see console

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.klc.co.nz/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://www.klc.co.nz/themes/KLC/responsivemultimenu.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
(index):1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.klc.co.nz/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://www.klc.co.nz/themes/KLC/typeit.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).typeIt is not a function
    at (index):97
```

because of this code in html

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.klc.co.nz/themes/KLC/responsivemultimenu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.klc.co.nz/themes/KLC/typeit.js"></script>
```

Either provide relative URL to these or change to https

Comment: Thank you so much. Those damned js paths again!